# How do I relate tables with different foreign key names in Kohana ORM?

Tags: php, kohana, kohana-orm

I'm building a Kohaha application to manage sip lines in asterisk.

I'm wanting to use ORM but I'm wondering how do relate certain tables that are already well established.

e.g. the table sip_lines looks like this.

```
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default           | Extra                       |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL              | auto_increment              |
| sip_name           | varchar(80)      | NO   | UNI | NULL              |                             |
| displayname        | varchar(48)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| line_num           | varchar(10)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| model              | varchar(12)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| mac                | varchar(16)      | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| areacode           | varchar(6)       | NO   | MUL | NULL              |                             |
| per_line_astpp_acc | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| play_warning       | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| callout_disabled   | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | 0                 |                             |
| notes              | varchar(80)      | NO   |     | NULL              |                             |
| last_update        | timestamp        | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP | on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+-------------------+-----------------------------+
```

sip_buddies is this:

```
+----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| Field          | Type                         | Null | Key | Default   | Extra          |
+----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
| id             | int(11)                      | NO   | PRI | NULL      | auto_increment | 
| name           | varchar(80)                  | NO   | UNI |           |                | 
| host           | varchar(31)                  | NO   |     |           |                | |                |
| lastms         | int(11)                      | NO   |     | 0         
*** snip ***
+----------------+------------------------------+------+-----+-----------+----------------+
```

The two tables are actually related as sip_lines.sip_name = sip_buddies.name

How do I relate them in Kohana ORM as this wouldn't be quite right would it?

```
<?php defined('SYSPATH') or die('No direct script access.');

/* A model for all the account information */
class Sip_Line_Model extends ORM
{
    protected $has_one = array("sip_buddies");
}

?>
```

EDIT: Actually, it'd be fair to say that these tables are not properly related with foreign keys!  doh.

EDIT: Looks like Kohana ORM is not that flexible.  ORM is probably not the way to go and works best for completely new projects where the data model can be altered.  The reason being that the key names must follow a specific naming convention or else they won't relate
in Kohana.

Comment: If this is a new project and it doesn't have to be done this way; you should consider making adjustments to your DB schema. It's better to relate data from different tables using ID's instead of names.

Comment: It's a new project on top of a preexisting database.  So I don't have the ability to change the field names exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not up to kohana ORM but up to your db design. It's always been a "rule" to use integer as foreign key and not varchar, I haven't seen a design like this for ages.

Add integer FKs or don't think of using ORM at all, just doesn't work that way.

EDIT:

And yes, if you really want to do it this way;

```
protected $has_one = array('buddy' => array('model' => 'sip_buddy', 'foreign_key' => 'name' ) );
```

Answer (score 0):

It's correct only if you plan on using a one-to-one relationship. However, if you plan on having one-to-many relationships, you'll want to use $has_many. Depending on your needs you may optionally create a model for the other table and use $belongs_to for that one.

It's all explained here: http://docs.kohanaphp.com/libraries/orm/starting

Comment: No it's not correct because I can use the table relationship features of ORM.  e.g. find_related_$child

It's as though they are not associated.